# Como dinamizar uma sequência numérica de 3 em 3 números seguindo a ordem?

Tags: javascript

Tipo:

1 2 3 ... 4 5 6 ... 7 8 9

E assim por diante.

## Exemplo

```js
var clic = 0;
function mais() {
  if (clic == 1) {
    document.getElementById('txt').textContent += "1 2 3 "
  } else if (clic == 2) {
    document.getElementById('txt').textContent += "4 5 6 "
  } else if (clic == 3) {
    document.getElementById('txt').textContent += "7 8 9 "
  } else {
    document.getElementById('btn').style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="mais" id="btn" onclick="mais(clic++)" />
<p id="txt">&nbsp;</p>
```

No exemplo acima coloquei um limite para cada clique, não é necessário limitar podendo ser ilimitado para o que necessito.

Sendo assim, apenas quero sempre jogar de 3 em 3 números pegando sempe a último número e dar continuidade na sequência.

**O que quero é automatizar e melhorar a função sem que precise definir manualmente os números e a sua ordem.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tem diversas formas, por exemplo, guardando os itens em um `Array()` e depois imprimindo todos em uma `div`.

***Exemplo:***

```js
var items = Array();
var div1 = document.getElementById("div1");
function moreItems(total)
{
  for(i = 0; i < total; i++)
  {
      items.push(items.length + 1);
  } 
  viewItems(items);
}

function viewItems(items)
{
  div1.innerHTML = '';
  for(i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
  {
      div1.innerHTML += items[i] + ' ';
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="div1"></div>
<button type="button" onclick="moreItems(3)">Acrescentar</button>
```

[***Outro exemplo***](http://jsbin.com/yofabasinu/1/edit?html,js,console,output)

<sub>***Observação:*** o código [html](/questions/tagged/html) vem antes do código [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) para não ter problemas e causar ***erros***.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Segue outras alternativas:

Temos que definir três variáveis no escopo global que irão funcionar como *inicialização*, outra como *condição*, e um contador de cliques.

## Exemplo 1

```js
var n = 0;
var i = 0;
var clic = 0;
function mais() {
  clic++
  i += 3 // condição
  if (clic) {
    for (var x = n; x < i; x++) {
      document.getElementById('txt').textContent += x + '\n'
    }
  }
  if (clic) {
    n += 3 // inicialização
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="mais" id="btn" onclick="mais(1)" />
<p id="txt">&nbsp;</p>
```

## Exemplo 2

```js
var clic = 0;
var num = document.getElementById("txt").textContent;

function mais() {
  var i = 0 + clic; // inicialização
  var n = 3 + clic; // condição
  for (var i; i < n; i++) {
    num += i + '\n';
  }
  document.getElementById("txt").textContent = num;
  clic += 3;
}
```

```html
<p id="txt">&nbsp;</p>
<input type="button" value="mais" onclick="mais()" />
```

> **NOTA** - O Script do **Exemplo 2** deve ser inserido no fim do documento HTML entre o `</body>` ... `</html>`, para evitar **falhas** na execução.
>
> A razão de termos colocado o elemento `<script>` perto do fim do arquivo HTML, é que o elemento HTML `<p id="txt"> &nbsp; </p>` é carregado pelo browser na ordem em que ele aparece no arquivo. Se o JavaScript é carregado primeiro ele deve afetar o elemento HTML abaixo dele, mas as vezes isso pode não funcionar, já que o JavaScript seria carregado antes do elemento HTML no qual ele deveria trabalhar.  Portanto, próximo ao fim da página, geralmente é a melhor estratégia.

Comment: em vez de colocar o `<script>` no final da pagina, poderia usar um `<script defer>` :)

Answer (score 1):

Usei jQuery

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  var n = 0;
  
  $("#click").click(function(){
    n += 3;
    var campo = $("#n").text();
    campo += n-2;
    campo += n-1;
    campo += n;
    $("#qtdeClick").text(n/3);
    $("#n").text(campo);
    $("#valorN").text(n);
  });
  
 });

</script>
<body>

  <input type="button" id="click" value="Clique"/>
  <p>Valor de N:<span id="valorN"></span></p>
  <p>QTDE de Clicks: <span id="qtdeClick"></span></p>
  <p id="n"></p>
</body>
```