# Auto ajuste tamanho real do select via option disponíveis

Tags: javascript, html, css, select, option

eu normalmente pesquiso e não perturbo a paciência dos membros aqui, mas dessa vez preciso especificadamente de um exemplo. Veja:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

    <select id="lista" size="4">
          <option value="A">01</option>
          <option value="B">02</option>
          <option value="C">03</option>
          <option value="D">04</option>
          <option value="E">05</option>
          <option value="F">06</option>
          <option value="G">07</option>
          <option value="H">08</option>
          <option value="I">09</option>
          <option value="J">10</option>
          <option value="k">11</option>
          <option value="L">12</option>
        </select>

    <button onclick="somar()">Carregar Mais</button>
</body>

<script>
    somar = function() {
        var A = document.getElementById('lista');
        var B = A.getElementsByTagName('option');
        var C = B.length;
        B.size = C;
    }
</script>

</html>
```

Note que estou iniciando o elemento `select` com tamanho[`size`] de *4 items* amostra, mas, o que pretendo é algo dinâmico - **auto ajuste da altura** do `select` conforme a quantidade de `option`. Por isso que na função do exemplo estou tentando percorrer os *ítems* pelo método `documentgetElementsByTagName('option')`. Na minha visão, achei que isso poderia ser a solução para um **incremento** à definir a propriedade `size`.

> **RESUMO** - *Dar jeito para definir automaticamente a propriedade `size` do elemento HTML [`select`] sem interveção humana, deixar a tarefa toda pro "script" ajustar para tamanho real. A idéia é de que não apresente a barra de rolagem vertical*

Comment: Pq vc coloca o script fora do body?

Comment: @dvd Li em algum lugar pela internet um artigo de um gringo escritor no qual lançou um livro sobre boas práticas web [Front-end] e tals. Nele ele dizia fortemente para que os desenvolvedores atentassem para deixar o(s) script no fim, depois do carregamento de todo conteúdo da página em si. Observe quando acessamos alguns web sites pesados por aí, tende a ter lentidão e vemos barra de status sempre notificando que ainda ha elementos a serem baixados/carregados. Isso é, o desenvolvedor introduziu diversos script no início e no corpo da página. Nos da a sensação de que o Navegador vai travar.

Comment: Sim, já li isso tb, mas quando diz "no fim", não quer dizer depois do body, mas no final dele. Pelo foi isso que entendi. Agora vc me deixou na dúvida rss. vou pesquisar...

Comment: @dvd Então, ha outros meios de se fazer isso. Mas alguns scripts requer que seja no início dependendo da programção pois ele deve enxergar o elemento HTML a ser atingido no DOM. Eu coloquei esse detalhe em um comentário dumas perguntas no qual fiz antigamente por aqui. Tem + detalhes, vou dar uma vasculhada e jaja e aponto algo a +.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está redefinindo o atributo `size` no elemento errado:

```
B.size = C;
```

O `B` são as `options` (`var B = A.getElementsByTagName('option');`).

O correto seria o `A`, que é a variável onde você armazenou o `select`:

```
A.size = C;
```

**Exemplo:**

```js
somar = function() {
  var A = document.getElementById('lista');
  var B = A.getElementsByTagName('option');
  var C = B.length;
  A.size = C;
}
```

```html
<select id="lista" size="4">
          <option value="A">01</option>
          <option value="B">02</option>
          <option value="C">03</option>
          <option value="D">04</option>
          <option value="E">05</option>
          <option value="F">06</option>
          <option value="G">07</option>
          <option value="H">08</option>
          <option value="I">09</option>
          <option value="J">10</option>
          <option value="k">11</option>
          <option value="L">12</option>
        </select>
<button onclick="somar()">Carregar Mais</button>
```

Se quiser que isso seja feito de forma automática, você pode colocar na função do evento `DOMContentLoaded`:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
  var A = document.getElementById('lista');
  var B = A.getElementsByTagName('option');
  var C = B.length;
  A.size = C;
});
```

```html
<select id="lista" size="4">
   <option value="A">01</option>
   <option value="B">02</option>
   <option value="C">03</option>
   <option value="D">04</option>
   <option value="E">05</option>
   <option value="F">06</option>
   <option value="G">07</option>
   <option value="H">08</option>
   <option value="I">09</option>
   <option value="J">10</option>
   <option value="k">11</option>
   <option value="L">12</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Pior que é verdade, vi que havia algo estranho. Até cheguei a pensar que era incompatibilidade entre navegadores, pois tô testando o projeto em 2 distintos. Isso é o que dá ficar horas e horas programando, chega uma hora meu amigo que você cai na sua própria contradição. rsrs

Comment: Putz! Trabalho há 20 anos com HTML e nunca ouvi isso, mas que bom se isso for verdade, será uma novidade pra mim. Eu geralmente uso o <head> para carregar libs. Mas, como disse, já li a respeito de colocar no final do <body> para melhorar a performance etc., mas nunca fora dele. Se bem que colocando no <head> eu nunca senti problemas.

Comment: Adicionei na resposta a ação no carregamento da página, era isso que queria?

Comment: Desculpe a demora em lhe dar um *feedback* estava eu a procurar a resposta que dei sobre minha pergunta onde menciono sobre o que nos estávamos falando - a inclusão do delimitador `script` depois do fechamento do `body`. A questão é essa daqui - https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/184284/41467 olhe no final de minha resposta + o comentário de um colega logo abaixo.

Comment: Legal! Vou dar uma pesquisada e te mando alguma novidade sobre o assunto.

Comment: Fiz umas pesquisas e testes, realmente o script funciona após o </body>, mas isso não é uma prática HTML válida, embora os navegadores façam vista grossa. O validador do W3C tb acusa o erro. Enfim, na minha opinião, prefiro, neste caso, usar no fim do <body>. Abs! :)